# Blazer transmission pan interchange options?

Tags: chevrolet, transmission, blazer, part-interchange

I have a 97 Chevy Blazer four-wheel drive with 4.3L V6 engine. The transmission pan is leaking because it has a hole in it; what transmission pan will interchange?

Answer (score 0):

According to what I'm seeing, there's a pretty good list of pans which will interchange. The pan should be from either a 4L60 or 4L60e from late '80's to early 2000's in most GM models. If you're thinking about getting one from a junk yard, you might also consider checking online. I'm seeing them new for ~$15-20 (SKP PN: SK103017). Even so, here's your interchange list:

```
BUICK       ROADMASTER      1992-1996
CADILLAC    BROUGHAM        1990-1992
CADILLAC    FLEETWOOD       1993-1996
CHEVROLET   ASTRO           1992-1998
CHEVROLET   BLAZER          1987-1998
CHEVROLET   C10 PICKUP      1982-1986
CHEVROLET   C1500 PICKUP    1988-1998
CHEVROLET   C1500 SUBURBAN  1992-1998
CHEVROLET   C20 PICKUP      1983-1986
CHEVROLET   C2500 PICKUP    1988-1998
CHEVROLET   CAMARO          1985-2002
CHEVROLET   CAPRICE         1985-1996
CHEVROLET   CORVETTE        1982-1996
CHEVROLET   EXPRESS 1500    1996-1999
CHEVROLET   EXPRESS 2500    1997-1999
CHEVROLET   G10             1987
CHEVROLET   G20             1985-1995
CHEVROLET   G30             1984-1995
CHEVROLET   IMPALA          1995-1996
CHEVROLET   K10 PICKUP      1982-1986
CHEVROLET   K1500 PICKUP    1988-1998
CHEVROLET   K1500 SUBURBAN  1992-1998
CHEVROLET   K20 PICKUP      1982-1986
CHEVROLET   K2500 PICKUP    1988-1996
CHEVROLET   K5 BLAZER       1984-1986
CHEVROLET   R10 PICKUP      1987
CHEVROLET   R1500 SUBURBAN  1989-1991
CHEVROLET   R20 PICKUP      1987
CHEVROLET   S10 BLAZER      1985-1994
CHEVROLET   S10 PICKUP      1983-1998
CHEVROLET   SILVERADO 1500  1999
CHEVROLET   SILVERADO 2500  1999
CHEVROLET   TAHOE           1995-1998
CHEVROLET   V10 PICKUP      1987
CHEVROLET   V1500 SUBURBAN  1989-1991
CHEVROLET   V20 PICKUP      1987
GMC         C1500 PICKUP    1984-1998
GMC         C1500 SUBURBAN  1994-1998
GMC         C2500 PICKUP    1989-1998
GMC         G2500           1990-1995
GMC         G3500           1995
GMC         JIMMY           1993-1998
GMC         K1500 PICKUP    1988-1998
GMC         K1500 SUBURBAN  1993-1998
GMC         K2500 PICKUP    1988-1996
GMC         R1500 PICKUP    1987
GMC         SAFARI          1995-1998
GMC         SAVANA 1500     1997-1999
GMC         SAVANA 2500     1997-1999
GMC         SIERRA 1500     1999
GMC         SONOMA          1992-1998
GMC         YUKON           1993-1998
OLDSMOBILE  BRAVADA         1997-1998
PONTIAC     FIREBIRD        1987-2002
```